# Why is my webpage too wide?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

***Disclaimer***: I am  very new to coding and this is my first question on this site, so please point out any lack of etiquette on my part. Also, off-topic related pointers on my coding are **welcome**.

I am building a portfolio page and have tried to make my page responsive (using **em** on images, text, padding etc.)

For some reason, the page displays too widely (need to scroll right to center content). Could someone point me in the right direction?

My code is as follows:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <!-- Start of Navigation -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul>
        <li id="name">Nathan King</li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navigation/Start of Content -->
  <div class="content">
  <div class="about">
    <!-- Start of About -->
    <a id="about"></a>
    <h2>Enter text about my education and skills<h2/><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i1JZv6/me.jpg" class=".img-responsive">
  </div><!-- End of About/Start of Portfolio -->
  <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio"> 
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="photo span4"></div>
      <div class="photo span4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Portfolio/Start of Contact -->
  <div class="contact">
    <a id="contact"></a>
    <h2>Contact me:</h2>
    <div id="soc-btn">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/#" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/#" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ccccff;
  width 100%;
}
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9099a2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
  color: white;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
nav a.active {
  background-color: #63799d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#name {
  float: left;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 1em 0.5em 1em 1em;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.about {
  padding: 4em 2em 2em 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #6d7993;
  width: 100%;
}

.about h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #d5d5d5;
}
.about img {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  font-family: calibri;
}

.portfolio {
  padding: 4em 2em 4em 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio h1 {
  color: Black;
}

.photo {
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #6d7993;
  padding: 4em;
  margin: 4em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em / 2em 1em 2em 1em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em / 2em 1em 2em 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em / 2em 1em 2em 1em;
}

.contact {
  padding: 4em 2em 4em 2em;
  background-color: #96858f;
  color: #d5d5d5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.soc-btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3b5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55acee;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

This is essential for responsive designs, as it tells the webpage to including padding and border in the element's total width and height. If you add this, your page displays fine.

This article online [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), explains this very well.

Take a look at your webpage here: https://jsfiddle.net/tfr8f8az/

*The `*` targets all elements.*

Comment: It will help the OP if you explained what that does and which of the elements in the HTML it fixes. I mean, you do have a link, but you should copy the relevant parts over to your answer.